# Encrypted external hard disk not recognized

Tags: fedora, encryption, disk-encryption, veracrypt

I'm using a dual boot system with Windows 8 and Fedora 31 KDE on my PC.

I've encrypted my external hard disk with VeraCrypt in Windows.

Windows recognizes this external hard drive and I can unlock the encrypted hard disk with VeraCrypt on Windows.

My problem is that Fedora does not recognize the encrypted hard disk. Although the hard disk is supplied with power, it does not appear in the device list.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install Verycrypt on your linux system?

Comment: Yes. And I've tried to find (and encrypt) my hard disk with VeraCrypt but this does not work.

Comment: You'd better decrypt it... does it show up in BIOS?

Comment: I can see it with this command `fdisk -l`

Comment: From Linux please show the commandline and output for `veracrypt /dev/YourExternalDevice /your/mount/point/dir` (properly changed for your system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your hard disk is connected, open a command line and type `sudo blkid` to list all available partitions. Graphically, you can see them with GParted.

Locate the partition that you wish to mount.

Once you know know it (something like "/dev/sdc1"), open Veracrypt GUI, choose a slot for mounting, and provide the path to the encrypted volume in the "Volume" field. For example, here I would mount /dev/sdc1 on the 5th Veracrypt mount point:
[image: Veracrypt GUI for mounting volume]
Click "Mount", provide the password / PIM / keyfile in the new popup as needed. It should make the job.

You can achieve the same result with command line :
`veracrypt -t /dev/sdc1`
You will then be prompted for other options : password, keyfiles, PIM...
You can also specify a mountpoint if you don't wish to take the first available Veracrypt mountpoint:
`veracrypt -t /dev/sdc1 /mnt/veracrypt5`
Please note that /mnt/veracryptX is where Veracrypt mounts volumes in openSUSE. It might differ for Fedora...

Comment: I would not have thought that anyone would still answer after such a long time. But it works as described. Thanks a lot!